# How Can I improve a POST Loop with JQUERY and JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I need to improve this function because i have an array of 20K rows and after loading this function, the browser runs out of resources.

//kairos length  > 20K rows;

```
function updateBD() {

    var resultado;

    for(var i = 1; i < kairos.length; ++i){

        if(kairos[i][0]=="I"){

            id = kairos[i][1];

            $.post('update.jsp', {

                f_codigo: kairos[i][1], 
                f_precio: kairos[i][8] 

            }, function(data){

                resultado = data.split('|');

                $("#"+resultado[0].trim()).html(resultado[1]);

            });

        }

    }

}
```

It shows `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` error.

Comment: net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Comment: If possible re-design to make pagination.

Comment: Please edit the error message into the question body.

Comment: Why not just "send" the entire array in the JSON format, deserialize on the backend and then do the processing?

Comment: instead of refreshing the content constantly with .html try .append

Comment: Perform the posts sequentially. It will be slow but with a greater chance of success.

Comment: How many of the 20k rows are likely to pass the test `if(kairos[i][0]=="I")` ?